# How do you keep VirtualBox network settings between Windows updates?

Tags: networking, windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a Windows 10 (laptop) host running Ubuntu 16.04 in a VirtualBox 5.2.8 VM. When I initially installed the VM, I used NAT as my network adapter 1 and a host-only adapter for #2.  This worked great until Windows updated.

To recreate the host-only adapter (attempting keep the previously assigned IP) I followed these steps:

```
Goal: Access VM at 192.168.56.101
1. In Global settings - Create new Host Only network adapter
2. Set Manual configured IP to 192.168.56.201 (or some other non-conflicting IP, on the same subnet)
3. On DHCP Server tab, Set DHCP address to 192.168.56.1 (or some other non-conflicting IP, on the same subnet)
4. Set upper/lower bound to 192.168.101 (this is the IP you want the VM to be accessible by from the host)
5. Enable "Configure Automatically"
6. Configure vm to use NAT for network 1, new Host only network for network 2
7. Reboot windows
```

This works and I can now reach the Internet from my Ubuntu VM and can also reach the VM from my Windows host (web, MySQL, ssh, etc).  But it's a bit of a pain to have to do this at the frequency that Windows updates.  Sooooo...Is there a way to keep this configuration from changing after a Windows update?

Comment: I've not used VBox on Win10, but its a suprise that windows updates would have an effect on your vbox nics. What specifically is happening?

Comment: It's pretty obvious when it happens - VirtualBox won't start the VM and throws an error.  From what I can tell the host-only networking connections get deleted.  I've had similar experiences on two additional systems (both Windows 10) but I just kinda put up with it because I didn't use it that often.  Now I'm using it daily and want to keep the environment as tight as possible.